# problems trying to navigate starting point of gdk_pixbuf with cario in C

Tags: gtk3

I have a stitched png file that is 100 frames of a gauge going from 0 to 100.  Each frame is 80x80.

I am loading the image into a pixbuf using gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file and attempting
to use gdk_cairo_set_source_pixbuf to navigate to the frame that I want to display.

I am getting the first frame when gdk_cairo_set_source_pixbuf(cr,pixbuf,0,0), however if I try to advance (for example at the gauge at 50%) and use gdk_cairo_set_source_pixbuf(cr,pixbuf,0,4000) ...I don't get anything.  I am getting no images other than when I am using 0,0.

I am new to this so any advice on what I may be doing wrong, or suggestions of alternate ways to do what I am looking to accomplish are appreciated. I have been searching for existing examples of someone using a subset of an image, but haven't been able to find any.

thank you.